# Data flow analysis for C++ program

Tags: c++, analysis, dataflow-diagram

I need to do some data flow analysis for C++ programs. Any open source tools that anyone can suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to evaluate if gcc and the intermediate front-end code transformation into `GIMPLE` or `GENERIC` (intermediate languages for workflow analysis for the code optimizer) fit for your purpose. This is fully free and open source. I just cannot tell you how exactly to output this tree representation but there are many gcc manuals online.

Answer (score 1):

Running the program and then stepping through and copying data / code flow into a separate running flowchart program works for me. Pencil and paper is good too but not so easy to manipulate or store afterwards.

Even if there is a tool to do this, I believe you are more likely to have a better understanding of the program with my approach.